# Custom menu items in admin

Tags: menus

I would like to add my own custom menu items to **Appearance > Menus**. How can this be done?

The best way to describe what I want to do:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `add_meta_box()` function ([working example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/#comment-1772)), and use `nav-menus` for the post-type.

John Morris also wrote about this in 2013: 
[How to Add a Fully Functional Custom Meta Box to WordPress Navigation Menus](http://www.johnmorrisonline.com/how-to-add-a-fully-functional-custom-meta-box-to-wordpress-navigation-menus/).

Comment: Thank you @Colin, the article helped me to find the solution.